# Multi extrude a vertex in the coordinate direction

Tags: modeling, vertices, coordinates

I' want to multi-extrude one vertex to the coordinate axis it is possible in blender without doing it manually here is an example.
[image]

Comment: Would you have a script that extrudes a single vertex along all the axis (both directions) or something different?

Comment: I hope some one can poit me to a script to do this, i do this every time in my modeling workflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've uploaded on GitHub a script that allows you to extrude selected vertices in all directions.

https://github.com/parameciostudio/extrude-vertices-all-directions

You can set the amount and choose whether select created vertices or not.

#### How to install

Open up `extrudeVerticesAllDirections.py` in the *Text Editor* and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

#### How to use

1. Select a mesh object and toggle into *Edit Mode* (<kbd>Tab</kbd>)
2. In the *MISC* tab of the Tool Shelf (<kbd>T</kbd>) you'll find a new *Extrude in all directions* panel
3. Set the extrusion amount and whether select new vertices or not (if not, original vertices will still selected)

Comment: Wow thank you so much let me test it to see how it works

Comment: Can I suggest sometime can you add a toggle to constrain the extrusion to Z, X or Y axis and thank you very much I use this every time in my workflow

Comment: This is what I can acomplishe with your'e addon

Comment: http://i60.tinypic.com/29o02fp.jpg